# Binding an Action to an Checkbox Checked event inside a MenuItem template

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, data-binding, caliburn.micro

I'm currently trying to create a MediaPlayer using Caliburn.Micro.
In my ShellView I have a Menu with MenuItems for 'File', 'Edit' and 'Categories'.
The Categories MenuItem has `List<CategoryModel>` as ItemSource.
The MenuItem has a ItemTemplate which is set to a Checkbox.

```
<Menu DockPanel.Dock="Top">
        <MenuItem Header="_File">
            <MenuItem Header="_Close" x:Name="Close"/>
        </MenuItem>
        <MenuItem Header="Edit">
            <MenuItem Header="Settings"/>
            <MenuItem Header="MediaData"/>
            <Separator/>
            <MenuItem Header="Reset"/>
        </MenuItem>
        <MenuItem Header="Categories" ItemsSource="{Binding AvailableCategories}">
            <MenuItem.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <CheckBox Content="{Binding DisplayText}" cal:Message.Attach="[Event Checked] = [Action ChangeSelectedPlaylist($dataContext)]"/>
                </DataTemplate>
            </MenuItem.ItemTemplate>
        </MenuItem>
    </Menu>
```

Now I want Caliburn to call a Method inside my ShellViewModel. But it always says it's unable to find the target for method ChangeSelectedPlaylist.

Now I've read about Visual Trees and caliburns 'TargetWithoutContext' but I cannot get it to run the Method specified.

All the examples I've found are using ContextMenus and ItemsControl. Which doesn't seem work with Checkboxes inside MenuItems.

Comment: Where is the `ChangeSelectedPlaylist` defined, is it a part of `ShellViewModel`? Can you share the method? Is `ShellView` a window and its datacontext is `ShellViewModel`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you have `ChangeSelectedPlaylist` method defined in `ShellViewModel`, you should use `TargetWithoutContext` with binding to the element, where `ShellViewModel` is set as `DataContext`. If it's a Window, the xaml should be something like that

```
<DataTemplate>
     <CheckBox Content="{Binding DisplayText}" 
               cal:Message.Attach="ChangeSelectedPlaylist($datacontext)"
               cal:Action.TargetWithoutContext="{Binding DataContext, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type Window}}}" />
</DataTemplate>
```

Comment: Thank you very much. The Problem was that the ShellView was a UserControl. I replaced it with a Window and with your code it works like a charm!

Answer (score 1):

You were on right track with TargetWithoutContext.

```
<CheckBox Content="{Binding DisplayText}"  cal:Message.Attach="ChangeSelectedPlaylist($datacontext)"
                                 cal:Action.TargetWithoutContext="{Binding DataContext, ElementName=mainMenu}" />
```

Where "mainMenu" is the name of Menu control. Complete Code

```
<Menu DockPanel.Dock="Top" cal:Action.TargetWithoutContext="{Binding DataContext, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}" x:Name="mainMenu">
            <MenuItem Header="_File">
                <MenuItem Header="_Close" x:Name="Close"/>
            </MenuItem>
            <MenuItem Header="Edit">
                <MenuItem Header="Settings"/>
                <MenuItem Header="MediaData"/>
                <Separator/>
                <MenuItem Header="Reset"/>
            </MenuItem>
            <MenuItem Header="Categories" ItemsSource="{Binding AvailableCategories}">
                <MenuItem.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <CheckBox Content="{Binding DisplayText}"  cal:Message.Attach="ChangeSelectedPlaylist($datacontext)"
                                 cal:Action.TargetWithoutContext="{Binding DataContext, ElementName=mainMenu}" />
                    </DataTemplate>
                </MenuItem.ItemTemplate>
            </MenuItem>
        </Menu>
```